Why were only Harry and Ginny allowed through the ring of fire and not the adults?
In the 6th Harry Potter film, The Half-Blood Prince, when the Weasleys' house was being burned down, Harry and Ginny get through the ring of fire. However once Ginny gets through, it closes and does not allow any one else through. Why did it ONLY allow those two in and not anyone else?




Bellatrix appears to have left a gap when setting the fire, presumably to allow herself to escape being encircled. She shuts it behind herself as she leaves. Harry is close enough that when he runs behind her, he is also able to use this small gap but Remus (and the others) are farther behind and so the gap closes.

MR. WEASLEY: Ginny, stay with your mother!
Without hesitation, she races for the reeds.
EXT. REEDS (SURROUNDING BURROW) - NIGHT (MOMENTS LATER)
Harry careens through the marsh, reeds flashing past, then spies Bellatrix. She GRINS, looking like a crazed wood nymph, then flits off, her LAUGHTER mocking him. As he pursues, FIRE SNAKES through the reeds toward him.
HARRY POTTER AND THE HALF-BLOOD PRINCE - Script

As has been pointed out in the answer to a highly related question, Ginny simply took advantage of a gap created by the adults who were trying to quell or manipulate the flames.

From a scripting perspective, this is just a way of allowing Harry and Ginny to confront the Death Eaters without having a bunch of adults around, noting that everyone involved is perfectly capable of Apparating short distances, but for some reason fails to do so, possibly because of the magical nature of the flames.
